# How to create table with dynamic number of columns MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create table in mysql.
There is `$column_str` which stores the **names** of the column.

If we have 3 columns it will be `$columns_str="123"`, 4 columns -> `$columns_str="1234"`

So, I need to create table using variable $columns_str.

This code creates table1 with 1 column: "123":

```
$columns_str="123"; $table_name = table1;
$connection->query("CREATE TABLE `kcup`.`$table_name` ( `$columns_str` TEXT NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;")
```

I need table with 3 columns: "1","2","3".

Help pls and thank you!

Comment: $column_str is always "123" ???

Comment: Whatever you're doing, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Please note that I answered what is exposed in your title. How to create a table with dynamic number of columns. From the text of your answer it is possible to see that your question is different. It is something like: "How to dynamically create a mysql table from php" (standard table, not table with dynamic number of columns)

Answer (score 2):

To create a table with three columns named `1`, `2`, and `3` when you have a variable `$columns_str="123"` you could use something like this;

```
<?php
$columns_str="123";
$table_name = 'table1';
$cols = str_split($columns_str);
$colQuery = '`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,';
foreach($cols as $col)
{
    $colQuery .= "
        `$col` TEXT NOT NULL,";
}
$colQuery .= "
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)";
$connection->query("CREATE TABLE `kcup`.`$table_name` ( $colQuery ) ENGINE = InnoDB;")
```

This would run the following SQL command;

```
CREATE TABLE `kcup`.`table1` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `1` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `2` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `3` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a table with dynamics columns, but you can simulate it with a table like this one

```
ID   FIELD    VALUE
1    ID       4345
1    NAME     PAUL
1    SURNAME  SMITH
2    ID       4346
2    NAME     MARC
2    SURNAME  BROWN
```

The PK of that table is ID, FIELD
Addyng a new field is equivalent to add a new row.

So adding the field EMAIL is equivalent to add two rows (one for PAUL and one for MARC) and you will have the following records

```
ID   FIELD    VALUE
1    ID       4345
1    NAME     PAUL
1    SURNAME  SMITH
2    ID       4346
2    NAME     MARC
2    SURNAME  BROWN
1    EMAIL    paul.smith@email.com
2    EMAIL    marc.brown@email.com
```

Comment: Yes ,we can create dynamic columns in sql . We use PIVOT function to create dynamic coumns in sql.

Comment: How with standard sql?

Comment: Please check this link http://www.sql2developers.com/2012/07/dynamic-columns-using-pivot-function-in.html

Comment: Is that a sort of view... or is it possible to insert delete update records from the pivot table?

Comment: I think select is possible but not sure for Update and Delete Operations.

Comment: So this is not a table... dynamics table are not possible. Only dynamics views based on table like the one that I exposed

Comment: Dynamic table creation is possible. See the below answer of Stu

Comment: This is not a dynamic table. This is a static table created with a dynamic php code. Basically the table once created is static.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74906/discussion-between-deep-kakkar-and-davide-lorenzo-marino).